# CSS - font-family - fallback with webfont-service?

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts, typography

For one of my projects I use a font hosted by a webfont-service. Without any fallback, the code looks like this: `font-family:'Amasis MT W01 italic';`
You see, the fontstyle (italic) is already included because that's what the client pays for. When I add a fallback to this, it works of course, but the fallback font is not italic which results in a drastic change in the look of the page. Is there any fix for this? Setting `Amasis MT W01 italic'` to italic resulst in a "double italic" font, so that's not an option.

Actually I need something like "if Amasis is not available use Helvetica in italic" only using CSS. I guess that won't be possible? Any alternatives?

Comment: Can't you just add a `font-style: italic` to the definition? It shouldn't change the way the Amasis font is rendered, but should change the fallback

Comment: Yes I though so too, but the Amasis is then displayed in extreme italic so I can't do that. And using the normal Amasis and putting it in italics "manually" would require the client to pay for another font (Amasis Regular).

Comment: I see. As far as I know, what you want isn't possible and your client may have to buy the second typeface. Maybe someone can come up with a workaround though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the actual font is italic, you should declare `font-style: italic` in the `@font-face` rule for it as well as in normal CSS code that uses the font, e.g.

```
font-family: 'Amasis MT W01 italic', Helvetica;
font-style: italic;
```

(It’s illogical to have the word *italic* in the name of a font *family*, but it’s just a name; you could just as well use `foobar` there, as long as you use the name consistently.)

I wonder, though, why Helvetica, the proverbial sans-serif font (which gets replaced by Arial in the vast majority of computers), would be a suitable substitute for a font in the Amasis family, which has strong serifs.

Comment: I just used Helvetica for the post, in the actual project it will be an other font. Also, the fonts aren't implemented via `@font-face`, they are delivered via JavaScript. After the script is placed into the header, the font can be used through declaring "Amasis MT W01 italic" in the CSS.

Comment: Then switch to `@font-face`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found solution here: http://spaceninja.com/2010/11/29/font-face-faux-styles/ It seams to work for me. Just make sure to define all @font-face rules as in example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu'; /* regular */ /* 'Amasis' in your case */
        src: url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.eot');
        /* more sources here */
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu'; /* italic */ /* 'Amasis' in your case */
        src: url('Ubuntu-R-webfont.eot');
        /* more sources here */
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

and then use it where needed as:

```
h2 {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu'; /* 'Amasis' in your case */
    font-style: italic;
}
```